# How to get data from listview in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I created a list, filled that with dynamic data.
Now I want all the data existing in listview.
How could I do that ?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
// if the dynamic data is a future data declare a bool and set to true when data recived 
//bool list = true; and setstate at the change of data
        body: list!=true?Container(child:Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator())): ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('${items[index]}'),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Maybe share some explanation of your code would be great